# plymouth causes system to hang on boot

Tags: boot, systemd, manjaro, plymouth, systemd-boot

My problem is the following: After my last update (pacman -Syu) my system hangs on boot, and I can't figure out the cause (it's driving me crazy, really)

Searching on the web I found out that this could be caused by a bad fstab file, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

The distro I'm using is Manjaro linux (it is based on Arch) and my Systemd version is 231

This is what journalctl -xb had to say about it

```
Oct 04 11:45:02 manjarobox systemd[350]: rescue.service: Faied at step EXEC spawning /bin/plymouth: No such file or directory
-Subject: Process /bin/plymouth could not be executed
-Defined-by: systemd
-Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-
-The process /bin/plymouth could not be executed and failed
-
-The error number returned by this process is 2
```

This is the output of ls -l /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Dec 22  2015 cronie.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/cronie.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Dec 27  2015 lm_sensors.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/lm_sensors.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 44 Dec 22  2015 ModemManager.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Dec 22  2015 NetworkManager.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Dec 22  2015 remote-fs.target -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/remote-fs.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Dec 22  2015 tlp.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/tlp.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jan 13  2016 ufw.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service
```

And my /etc/fstab file looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# DEVICE DETAILS: /dev/sda1 UUID=c52d9ae9-48a8-487c-931b-77deedf8e242 LABEL=DskA_Linux
# DEVICE DETAILS: /dev/sda5 UUID=170E967E185647C6 LABEL=DskD_Files
# DEVICE DETAILS: /dev/sda6 UUID=eeaa09fa-4ace-4e5a-8fef-170a18e41940 LABEL=DskE_Swap
UUID=c52d9ae9-48a8-487c-931b-77deedf8e242 / ext4 defaults 0 1
#UUID=170E967E185647C6 /mnt/Files ntfs-3g defaults 0 1
#UUID=eeaa09fa-4ace-4e5a-8fef-170a18e41940 swap swap defaults 0 0
```

Also, I have never installed plymouth, nor do I intend to, if I can help it.

What can I do to solve this? :S

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, and there are many causes for a this problem it seems (fstab misconfiguration, orphan config files, etc), but for me using 'grep -r plymouth /' and then deleting the statements calling plymouth solved it

Answer (score 0):

### Manjaro Linux 5.9 booting in a circular loop to the emergency maintenance root shell

Never getting to a GUI screen!  So you have to know a few CLI instructions to fix your problem and locate the source issue of this problem.
I had this same problem of script files calling for /usr/bin/plymouth on Manjaro 5.9 and I upgraded to Manjaro 5.10 and had same issue with failling to boot up to a GUI desktop (KDE Plasma I believe) and falling back to an emergency maintenance root shell.  Type your "ROOT PASSWORD"  to login to this emergency maintenance root shell.  I believe your in single user mode.

There was a dbus error  file not found /run/dbus/dbus_xxx_socket.
The dbus daemon was not running  `ps aux | grep dbus`
Command `dbus-monitor` failed to execute.

I think there was a conflict between dbus and dbus-x11 Command 'pacman -S dbus'  corrected the dbus problem,  yet the missing /usr/bin/plymouth still existed.
I thought maybe moving from linux59 to linux510 might clear up the script.  But no it did not clear up the problem.

`journalctl -xb`   or `journalctl -b -i -p4`  These are the journal commands to use.

`journalctl -xb > My_journalctl_error1.txt`   Will save a copy on your hard disk to post the single error line, later to a forum like this.

Further more I could not connect to the internet  using "nmcli" Network Manager command line interface using the existing wifi in the laptop a Broadcom BRM4313 (or 4727 chip).  So I used USB tethering from my android cellphone to access the internet to upgrade the computer software using the "pacman" command.  This was an attempt to see if upgraded Linux would use different script files and overwrite the problem error.  Opps, No Deal!

I plugged in my android cell phone with a USB cable to the laptop computer, and wrny into settings ---> Networking ---->  turned on USB Tethering.  I also turned "OFF" the data-saver setting   to allow fast download of kernel update files, 150 megabytes in   size.  Or much smaller "dbus" packages.

```
ip a s
ifconfig enp0s20u2  up
ip a s
ping -c 3 he.net
ping -c 3 8.8.4.4   the google DNS server, got me a NO route to network.

pacman -Syu
pacman -S dbus

sudo mhwd-kernel -i linux510

grep -R -n plymouth /etc
```

So I believe the solution is to remove the plymouth  from the script files below

```
/etc/systemd/display-manager.service   file at line 5  plymouth-quit.service
/etc/systemd/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service   file at line 14  plymouth-quit-wait.service
```